# Difference between DesignWidth and Width in UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

When I create a new `UserControl` in WPF, studio creates some XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MOG.Objects.Date.Calender"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In `UserContol` I can also add Width property. What is difference between `DesignWidth` and `Width`?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`d:DesignHeight` and `d.DesignWidth` are for the Designer (the WYSIWYG), in Visual Studio or in Expression Blend. *`Height`* and *`Width`* are actually for runtime.

Comment: This answer is simple and straightforward. Too much unneeded information in the accepted anwer

Answer (score 31):

Properties `d:DesignHeight` and `d:DesignWidth="300"` are used because ([`Source`](http://wpftutorial.net/DesigntimeVsRuntime.html)):

- UserControls are not embedded in a parent view. `Width` and `Height` are not set.
- Constructor of the root-element is not called. Root Element is replaced by the designer. ViewModel is not created.
- Controls behave different. No mouse and keyboard events.
  Design time extensions loaded

To improve the design experience, Microsoft provides special designtime attributes that can be added to any WPF element and serve as a hint for the design tool.

All that is used in the prefix `d:` is used to design mode, these include properties such as:

`d:DesignWidth`

`d:DesignHeight`

`d:LayoutOverrides`